# The referrer null does not match does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key

Tags: google-api

I've setup a browser API key  and have added `*.mydomain.com/*' in the referrer section. Hit save, waited for well over the 5 minutes.

When performing and API call I get the following error:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => ipRefererBlocked
                            [message] => The referrer null does not match does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
                            [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=xxxxxxxxx
                        )

                )

            [code] => 403
            [message] => The referrer null does not match does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
        )

)
```

If I leave the referrer section blank in the Google Dev Console, everything works. Do I need to specify the referrer in code somewhere also?

The Call using https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient:

```
$path = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels';

$response = $this->client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod( 'get' )
    ->setUrl( $path )
    ->setData( [ 'key' => $this->key, 'part' => 'id', 'forUsername' => $user_handle ] )
    ->send();
```

Which sends:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername={USER_NAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The website resides at http://sub.mydomain.com

Comment: How are you calling the API?

Comment: added the call to question

Comment: What's the value of the "Referrer" HTTP request header for the GET https://www.googleapis.com/... request? Sometimes browser extensions block the referrer.